# Ionic Controller and Service Structure

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm pretty new to Ionic and AngularJS. I tried to create a note app but my controllers.js did not seem to understand services.js. What do I have to do to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

And this is my code look like

app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers' ,'starter.services'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl : 'templates/list.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('edit', {
    url: '/edit/:Id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/edit.html',
    controller : 'EditCtrl'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('add', {
    url: '/add',
    templateUrl : 'templates/edit.html',
    controller : 'AddCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
}());
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, NoteStore) {
  $scope.notes = NoteStore.list();
});

.controller('EditCtrl', function($scope, $state, NoteStore) {
  $scope.title = "Edit";
  $scope.note = angular.copy(NoteStore.get($state.params.Id));

  $scope.save = function() {
    NoteStore.update($scope.note);
    $state.go('list')
  };
});

.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $state, NoteStore) {
  $scope.title = "New Note";
  $scope.note = {
    id: new Date().getTime().toString()
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    NoteStore.create($scope.note);
    $state.go('list')
  };
});
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('NoteStore', function() {
    var notes = [];

  return {
    list : function() {
        return notes;
    },

    get : function(noteId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        if (notes[i].id === noteId) {
          return notes[i];
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    },

    create : function(note) {
      notes.push(note);
    },

    update : function(note) {
      for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        if (notes[i].id === note.id) {
          notes[i] = note;
          return;
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
        </ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-nav-view>
      </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
<ion-view view-title="My Notes">

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a href="#/add" class="button icon ion-android-add"></a>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <div class = "list">
            <a href="#/edit/{{note.id}}" class = "item" ng-repeat = "note in notes">
                <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{note.description}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

edit.html

```
<ion-view view-title="{{title}}">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="note.title">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-input">
                <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Description" ng-model="note.description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding">
                <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Could be a question typo, but your `list` state is missing a controller reference.

Comment: I already add a ng-controller on the **list.html**

Comment: When I left all the controllers in the same file with **app.js**, it works. But when i try to separate them in to 2 files, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What is the **exact** problem? What do you mean by, "did not seem to understand services.js"

Comment: It's okay now. I don't know what is the problem, but it's just working and I did not change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you separate it into separate files first make sure you load the files in your index.html

so for each controller or service js file you will need in your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//path to js file"></script>
```

The next thing you need to do is inject your services and your controller into your main app.module which you did do here:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers' ,'starter.services'])
```

You also need to inject your service into you controller which you did not do so in

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
```

you need to inject `'stater.services'`

so it should look like

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])
```

then in your controller you can inject whatever factory you need

```
.controller('EditCtrl', function(NoteStore){})
```

each module needs to have the other modules it depends on injected into it. 
For example on my app i also inject ionic into my controllers and services.

That should get it working for you. If you want me to post more examples let me know.

Comment: I already tried that, but it still not working. I also tried to inject in each controller but no result.
I make this based on the Tabs template project of Ionic and it look exactly the same, but mine's not working

Comment: You must have done something wrong injecting it or did not include the files on the correct order in your index.html. Order matters.  Can you post your index. Html code?

Comment: After I eat I can make a ionic playground and set it up for too if you can't get it working.

Comment: Okay, I already post all my file. Thank in advance, sir. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's okay now. I don't know what is the problem, but it's just working and I did not change a thing. Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!!! 
In the controllers.js you can't end a controller and start another. 
If you want to use multiple controllers on the same JS file, you have to use semicolon only on the last controller.
I.E. You have 3 controllers

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function(){})
.controller('EditCtrl', function(){})
.controller('AddCtrl', function(){});
```

Only the last controller have to end with semicolon.